why flutter web can not potentially work with double and broke type casting?
Why is there a potential problem with type casting in flutter web?
I have the following code
model Range Value{
final double start = 21; 
final double end =32} 

final mapperExample extension on RangeModel{ 
start: start.asNum.toDouble() ?? 0, 
end: end.asNum.toDouble() ?? 0 }

Why does this code potentially, when it ends up in flutter web, give me an error and cannot work with values ​​as doubles, even though I literally cast it to a floating point in my code? how to bypass this limitation and force the web to accept 21.0, for example
in the mobile application everything works fine, but on the web the dart code turned into js can no longer work with floating point. I saw threads where it was discussed that js can do this, but if you do a toDouble cast it should work, but in my case the js code continues to think that a floating point number is an integer

This is workaround issue check if helps:
class RangeModel {
  final double start;
  final double end;

  RangeModel(this.start, this.end);
}

extension MapperExample on RangeModel {
  double get startAsDouble => start + 0.0; // Ensure double by adding 0.0
  double get endAsDouble => end + 0.0; // Ensure double by adding 0.0
}


Now, when you access startAsDouble or endAsDouble, Dart will treat the values as double, even after compilation to JavaScript.
Hope this helps.

I found the issue and the previous answer helped me to find out. It is not the greatest idea, but it finally worked and fine for demo version. The reason is that js cast int or double to Number and then js can not understand that it is 1000.0, it just makes it 1000. So i got the error about int is not subtype of double in web, so when i make  something like start + 0.1 it finally started to treat it as a double and i have something like 1000.134234 But I repeat it IS NOT the great idea. If you use only mobile app you def do not need this
